# SCRIPT70: Permission denied Accessing iFrame in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I am having some issues in IE with uploading files through a hidden iFrame. Actually the file upload is working fine but my jQuery code to display the success dialog and add the link to a table is not firing. Using the IE developer tools I discovered SCRIPT70: Permission denied error message. This is working fine in Chrome so I'm at a loss to what the issue is in IE. I should mention I am using IE10 so I imagine the issue exist in the previous versions of IE as well.

Essentially what I am trying to do is simulate Ajax like file upload using a hidden iFrame since we have to support legacy browsers. When the iFrame post successfully its response has a div which contains JSON which I read then parse. The data from the JSON is used to display a message to the user indicating the status of the file upload as well and add the link to the page by adding a row to a table. However in IE the chechUploadResponse function does not even appear to be firing.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#btnPrint').click(openPrintTimesheetWindow);
$('#date').change(postback);
$('#employee').change(postback);
$('#client').change(postback);
$('#btnUpload').click(uploadFile);
$("#uploadFrame").on("load", function () {
    $('#uploadFrame').contents().find('#userFile').change(uploadFileChanged);
    checkUploadResponse();
    });
});

function postback()
{
$('#timesheetPrintFilter').submit();
}

function uploadFileChanged()
{
$('#ajaxBusy').show();
    $('#uploadFrame').contents().find('#uploadForm').submit();
}

function uploadFile()
{
    var employeeId  = $('#init_employee').val();
    var periodDate  = $('#init_periodEndDate').val();

    $('#uploadFrame').contents().find('#employeeId').val(employeeId);
    $('#uploadFrame').contents().find('#periodEndDate').val(periodDate);
    $('#uploadFrame').contents().find('#userFile').click();
}

function checkUploadResponse()
{
    var response = $('#uploadFrame').contents().find('#uploadResponse').text();

    if (response != null && response != '')
    {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        if (response.status == "ERROR")
        {
            $("#dialog").html(response.message);
            $("#dialog").dialog({ buttons: { "OK": function() { $(this).dialog("close");}}, title: "Error" });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#dialog").html(response.message);
            $("#dialog").dialog({ buttons: { "OK": function() { $(this).dialog("close");}}, title: "Success" });

            var url = response.url;
            var tsaid = response.tsaid;
            var name = response.name;

            var row = '<tr id="tsaid-' + tsaid + '">' +
                    '<td width="80%" valign="top" align="left">' +
                        '<a href="' + url + '">' + name + '</a>' +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>';

            $("#tsAttachment").append(row);
        }
    }

    $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
}
```

Hidden iFrame:

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="timesheet-upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728" />
    <input type="hidden" name="employeeId" id="employeeId" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="periodEndDate" id="periodEndDate" value="" />
    <input type="file" name="userFile" id="userFile" />
</form>
```

Here is an example response from the hidden iFrame after being posted

```
<div id="uploadResponse">{"status":"SUCCESS","message":"Timesheet successfully uploaded","url":"uploads\/2013\/Aug\/1-49cd1c0217abf676505b349ec88bb5a42b1d5631e41232f08be3b0dced9f65e2.pdf","name":"How To Write A Cover Letter.pdf","tsaid":15}</div>
<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="timesheet-upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728" />
    <input type="hidden" name="employeeId" id="employeeId" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="periodEndDate" id="periodEndDate" value="" />
    <input type="file" name="userFile" id="userFile" />
</form>
```

Comment: It turns out this may have been a jQuery bug. I upgraded from jQuery-1.9.1 to jQuery-1.10.2 and that seemed to resolve the issue for me. I found this reported on the jQuery website for anyone that's interested. Hope this helps anyone who is having similar issues.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13936

Answer (score 10):

I know this post is a bit old, but this may help future seekers for the mystery around IE.

The solution proposed needs to be applied to ***the library of jQuery***.
The problem is explained here: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802251/script70-permission-denied-error-when-trying-to-access-old-document-from-reloaded-iframe

and the solution is given here:

https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/5b3048605655285a81b06fbe4f49f2a14a8d790f/src/sizzle.js#L472-L480

An alternative solution is located under this ticket at jQuery bug reporting site: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14535
It is posted by user **muley** and a JSFiddle is provided as well: http://jsfiddle.net/xqb4s/

The code that needs to be added in jQuery library in this case is:

```
// MY EDIT - this try/catch seems to fix IE 'permission denied' errors as described here:
// http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14535
try{
    document === document; //may cause permission denied
}
catch(err){
    document = window.document; //resets document, and no more permission denied errors.
}
```

Under the:

```
function Sizzle( selector, context, results, seed )
```

Comment: This solved my issue and saved my day! My scenario is, the page inside iframe calls a jquery based function of outer document once inner one is loaded, then the jquery of outer document is not working any more, just throwing `access is denied` error.

Comment: The `document === document` line will be removed by JS uglify/minify tool, any alternative ways to trigger the permission denial? Thanks.

Comment: I am using jquery 2.2.4; can't find the solution or locate such code. please provide for this version.